# Dependency properties with custom control aren't displaying

Tags: c#, wpf, custom-controls, mahapps.metro

I have a custom control:

```
<Button x:Class="TESterUI.CustomControls.ToolbarButton"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TESterUI.CustomControls"
        xmlns:iconPacks="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/iconpacks"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Height="35" Width="35">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <iconPacks:PackIconModern Kind="{Binding TbIcon}"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding TbText}" FontSize="12"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Button>
```

and its backing:

```
public partial class ToolbarButton : Button
{
    public ToolbarButton()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public string TbText
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TbTextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TbTextProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TbTextProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("TbText", typeof(string), typeof(Button), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public PackIconModernKind TbIcon
    {
        get { return (PackIconModernKind)GetValue(TbIconProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TbIconProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TbIconProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("TbIcon", typeof(PackIconModernKind), typeof(Button), new PropertyMetadata(null));
}
```

and implementation:

```
<customs:ToolbarButton TbText="Day" TbIcon="CalendarDay"/>
```

But the button shows up without an icon and no text. This is my first crack at custom controls, I'm not really sure where to go. I've tried to make it a string property and convert from enum with Parse, that didn't work, either and then I learned that WPF has internal string to enum conversion so I took all the conversion out. At the very least, the text should show, I would think.

Comment: Besides the wrong dependency property declaration, you have to bind to the control's own properties in its XAML, e.g. by specifying RelativeSource: `Text="{Binding TbText, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Button}}"`

Comment: Note that having a XAML file for a derived Button is uncommon. A custom control usually has a default Style in Themes\Generic.xaml. See [Control Authoring Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/control-authoring-overview).

Comment: That did it, @Clemens, thank you. And I assume by the wrong dependency property declaration, you were talking about setting the typeof(Button) to typeof(ToolbarButton)? I will look at your link for the more common way to do this.